# how many algorithms are there to use in HAProxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Hie, could someone please list all the available algorithms for HAPRoxy with simple definition of each.

Regards

Comment: Do you mean load-balancing algorithms?

Comment: yes load balancing algorithms used in HAproxy

Answer (score 15):

From the manual:

```
<algorithm> is the algorithm used to select a server when doing load
            balancing. This only applies when no persistence information
            is available, or when a connection is redispatched to another
            server. <algorithm> may be one of the following :

  roundrobin  Each server is used in turns, according to their weights.
              This is the smoothest and fairest algorithm when the server's
              processing time remains equally distributed. This algorithm
              is dynamic, which means that server weights may be adjusted
              on the fly for slow starts for instance. It is limited by
              design to 4095 active servers per backend. Note that in some
              large farms, when a server becomes up after having been down
              for a very short time, it may sometimes take a few hundreds
              requests for it to be re-integrated into the farm and start
              receiving traffic. This is normal, though very rare. It is
              indicated here in case you would have the chance to observe
              it, so that you don't worry.

  static-rr   Each server is used in turns, according to their weights.
              This algorithm is as similar to roundrobin except that it is
              static, which means that changing a server's weight on the
              fly will have no effect. On the other hand, it has no design
              limitation on the number of servers, and when a server goes
              up, it is always immediately reintroduced into the farm, once
              the full map is recomputed. It also uses slightly less CPU to
              run (around -1%).

  leastconn   The server with the lowest number of connections receives the
              connection. Round-robin is performed within groups of servers
              of the same load to ensure that all servers will be used. Use
              of this algorithm is recommended where very long sessions are
              expected, such as LDAP, SQL, TSE, etc... but is not very well
              suited for protocols using short sessions such as HTTP. This
              algorithm is dynamic, which means that server weights may be
              adjusted on the fly for slow starts for instance.

  source      The source IP address is hashed and divided by the total
              weight of the running servers to designate which server will
              receive the request. This ensures that the same client IP
              address will always reach the same server as long as no
              server goes down or up. If the hash result changes due to the
              number of running servers changing, many clients will be
              directed to a different server. This algorithm is generally
              used in TCP mode where no cookie may be inserted. It may also
              be used on the Internet to provide a best-effort stickiness
              to clients which refuse session cookies. This algorithm is
              static by default, which means that changing a server's
              weight on the fly will have no effect, but this can be
              changed using "hash-type".

  uri         This algorithm hashes either the left part of the URI (before
              the question mark) or the whole URI (if the "whole" parameter
              is present) and divides the hash value by the total weight of
              the running servers. The result designates which server will
              receive the request. This ensures that the same URI will
              always be directed to the same server as long as no server
              goes up or down. This is used with proxy caches and
              anti-virus proxies in order to maximize the cache hit rate.
              Note that this algorithm may only be used in an HTTP backend.
              This algorithm is static by default, which means that
              changing a server's weight on the fly will have no effect,
              but this can be changed using "hash-type".

              This algorithm supports two optional parameters "len" and
              "depth", both followed by a positive integer number. These
              options may be helpful when it is needed to balance servers
              based on the beginning of the URI only. The "len" parameter
              indicates that the algorithm should only consider that many
              characters at the beginning of the URI to compute the hash.
              Note that having "len" set to 1 rarely makes sense since most
              URIs start with a leading "/".

              The "depth" parameter indicates the maximum directory depth
              to be used to compute the hash. One level is counted for each
              slash in the request. If both parameters are specified, the
              evaluation stops when either is reached.

  url_param   The URL parameter specified in argument will be looked up in
              the query string of each HTTP GET request.

              If the modifier "check_post" is used, then an HTTP POST
              request entity will be searched for the parameter argument,
              when it is not found in a query string after a question mark
              ('?') in the URL. Optionally, specify a number of octets to
              wait for before attempting to search the message body. If the
              entity can not be searched, then round robin is used for each
              request. For instance, if your clients always send the LB
              parameter in the first 128 bytes, then specify that. The
              default is 48. The entity data will not be scanned until the
              required number of octets have arrived at the gateway, this
              is the minimum of: (default/max_wait, Content-Length or first
              chunk length). If Content-Length is missing or zero, it does
              not need to wait for more data than the client promised to
              send. When Content-Length is present and larger than
              <max_wait>, then waiting is limited to <max_wait> and it is
              assumed that this will be enough data to search for the
              presence of the parameter. In the unlikely event that
              Transfer-Encoding: chunked is used, only the first chunk is
              scanned. Parameter values separated by a chunk boundary, may
              be randomly balanced if at all.

              If the parameter is found followed by an equal sign ('=') and
              a value, then the value is hashed and divided by the total
              weight of the running servers. The result designates which
              server will receive the request.

              This is used to track user identifiers in requests and ensure
              that a same user ID will always be sent to the same server as
              long as no server goes up or down. If no value is found or if
              the parameter is not found, then a round robin algorithm is
              applied. Note that this algorithm may only be used in an HTTP
              backend. This algorithm is static by default, which means
              that changing a server's weight on the fly will have no
              effect, but this can be changed using "hash-type".

  hdr(<name>) The HTTP header <name> will be looked up in each HTTP request.
              Just as with the equivalent ACL 'hdr()' function, the header
              name in parenthesis is not case sensitive. If the header is
              absent or if it does not contain any value, the roundrobin
              algorithm is applied instead.

              An optional 'use_domain_only' parameter is available, for
              reducing the hash algorithm to the main domain part with some
              specific headers such as 'Host'. For instance, in the Host
              value "haproxy.1wt.eu", only "1wt" will be considered.

              This algorithm is static by default, which means that
              changing a server's weight on the fly will have no effect,
              but this can be changed using "hash-type".

  rdp-cookie
  rdp-cookie(name)
              The RDP cookie <name> (or "mstshash" if omitted) will be
              looked up and hashed for each incoming TCP request. Just as
              with the equivalent ACL 'req_rdp_cookie()' function, the name
              is not case-sensitive. This mechanism is useful as a degraded
              persistence mode, as it makes it possible to always send the
              same user (or the same session ID) to the same server. If the
              cookie is not found, the normal roundrobin algorithm is
              used instead.

              Note that for this to work, the frontend must ensure that an
              RDP cookie is already present in the request buffer. For this
              you must use 'tcp-request content accept' rule combined with
              a 'req_rdp_cookie_cnt' ACL.

              This algorithm is static by default, which means that
              changing a server's weight on the fly will have no effect,
              but this can be changed using "hash-type".

<arguments> is an optional list of arguments which may be needed by some
            algorithms. Right now, only "url_param" and "uri" support an
            optional argument.

            balance uri [len <len>] [depth <depth>]
            balance url_param <param> [check_post [<max_wait>]]
```

The load balancing algorithm of a backend is set to roundrobin when no other
  algorithm, mode nor option have been set. The algorithm may only be set once
  for each backend.